# Is there a way to prioritize an object on a form?

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, timer

I have a form where there is a timer in the corner that counts to 10 repeatedly. The "Next" button below triggers a reading that the user is taking every few seconds. When I hit the "Next" button the UI freezes while data is being taken and that includes the textbox that the timer is writing to. So the visible number that the user sees is frozen for 2 seconds every time they press the button. Is there a way to keep the text box being updated every second?

Here is the tick event:

```
private void timer_Counter_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Ticker == 9)
    {
        Ticker = 0;
    }
    else { Ticker++; }
    txtbx_Timer.Text = Ticker.ToString();
}
```

and here is the timer initiation:

```
timer_Counter = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer_Counter.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Counter_Tick);
timer_Counter.Interval = 1000;
timer_Counter.Start();
```

[image]

Comment: You need to show us the code of the button's Click event handler. You may also want to search for keywords like multithreading and asynchronous programming. The issue is not that the textbox is not "prioritized". It's just that when you click the button, some work is being carried out which blocks the whole UI thread. There are several ways to get around that which depends on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Your code in the button click event is being ran on the UI thread. You won't be able to keep the form reactive without putting your code inside your button click into another thread.

Answer (score 0):

@ahmed & @Franck, following your comments I discovered backgroundworker and I put the heavy processing on a different thread which seems to have solved the issue. Thanks!